# Beautiful soup excluding inner <li> and <ul> tags on a parent <li> tag .getText()

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anaconda

Okay so the data I am trying to get looks like this;

```
  <li class="expandable"> Criminal
    <ul class="subPracticeAreas" style="display:none">
        <li> Appellate< /li>
        <li>Crimes against the person</li>
        <li> Drugs< /li>
        <li>Environmental and planning offences</li>
        <li> Extradition< /li>
        <li>Fraud</li>
        <li> Juvenile justice</li>
        <li>Mental illness</li>
        <li> Proceeds of crime / money laundering</li>
        <li>Property offences</li>
        <li> Sexual assault</li>
        <li>Traffic</li>
        <li> White collar and corporate crime</li>
        <li>Work health and safety</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="expandable"> Appellate
    <ul class="subPracticeAreas" style="display:none">
        <li> Civil appeals</li>
        <li>Criminal appeals</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="expandable"> Inquests / inquiries
    <ul class="subPracticeAreas" style="display:none">
        <li> Commissions and other Inquiries</li>
        <li>Coronial inquests</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

So I want to be able to achieve these **objectives**;

1. Grab the parent li tag's text, store it as a variable (to be used as a dictionary key) e.g. in the first list I want to only grab "Criminal".
2. Grab each child li tag's text (individually of coarse), store it as a dict item with the key "Criminal" (as said above).

Rinse and repeat process for each li class="expandable" section.

What I have so far (which is not working, as you could imagine);

```
aop_list_headers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"expandable"})

for aop_list in aop_list_headers:
    aop_key_name = aop_li_head.getText().strip()
```

So this returns all the text from the respective parent li (e.g. for the first iteration of the above loop I get the following;

```
CriminalAppellateCrimes against the personDrugsEnvironmental and planning offencesExtraditionFraudJuvenile justiceMental illnessProceeds of crime/money launderingProperty offencesSexual assaultTrafficWhite collar and corporate crimeWork health and safety
```

How do I stop this from going through each li's text (as I can see it is happening because the parent li goes around the whole list...

I have not included how I will do the 2nd objective (made above), as I am stuck on the 1st objective....

All help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: what's `aop_li_head` in the for loop? also, i fail to see how you can build the dict consisting of (for example, correct me if i'm wrong): `{'Inquests / inquiries': ['Commissions and other Inquiries', 'Coronial inquests']}` separating steps 1 and 2.

Comment: sorry `aop_li_head =  #text value in the <li class="expandable">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the extend() function in BeautifulSoup like so;

```
for html in html_list:
    # Storing the unwanted child element
    unwanted = html.find("ul",{"class":""subPracticeAreas""})
    # Extracting the child <ul> data
    unwanted.extract()
```

Therefore turning this;

```
<li class="expandable"> Criminal
  <ul class="subPracticeAreas" style="display:none">
    <li> Appellate< /li>
    <li>Crimes against the person</li>
    <li> Drugs< /li>
    <li>Environmental and planning offences</li>
    <li> Extradition< /li>
    <li>Fraud</li>
    <li> Juvenile justice</li>
    <li>Mental illness</li>
    <li> Proceeds of crime / money laundering</li>
    <li>Property offences</li>
    <li> Sexual assault</li>
    <li>Traffic</li>
    <li> White collar and corporate crime</li>
    <li>Work health and safety</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Into this;

```
  <li class="expandable"> Criminal </li>
```

Therefore leaving me with the parent

elements I needed to gather.

To complete both tasks mentioned in my original comment, I used the following code.

```
aop_find = page_soup.find(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(aop)), recursive=True)

if aop_find != None:

    aop_list_headers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"expandable"})

    #counter
    aop_counter = 1

    #AOP prefix
    aop_prefix = "AOP "

    aop_result = {}

    # Getting the dictionary key
    for aop_li_head in aop_list_headers:
        # storing the sub practice groups data
        aop_values = aop_li_head.find("ul",{"class":"subPracticeAreas"})

        # Extracting the child <ul> data
        unwanted = aop_li_head.find("ul",{"class":"subPracticeAreas"})
        unwanted.extract()

        #key name (e.g. "Crime ")
        aop_key_name = aop_li_head.getText().strip() + " "

        aop_counter = 1

        # Finding the text in each vaule
        for aop_value in aop_values:
            aop_value = aop_value.getText().strip()

            aop_result[aop_prefix + str(aop_key_name) + str(aop_counter)] = aop_value
            aop_counter = aop_counter + 1

    # Appending loop results
    page_results.append(aop_result)
```

Thanks for everyones input!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can access all the child elements of your intended dict key via a `find_all` using the recursive tag:

```
children = soup.find_all("li", { "class" : "expandable" }, recursive=False)
for child in children:
   print child.getText()
```

Alternatively you can get all the `li` text elements whose parent (ul)'s parent has the class "expandable"

```
def get_children(elem):
    return (tag.name == 'li' and
        tag.parent.parent.name == 'li' and
        'expandable' in tag.parent.parent['class'])

for child in soup.find_all(get_children):
    print child.getText() #li text
```